# Searching for a table based on values contained in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a `reason_id` foreign key. I need to map that back to its primary table. I have searched our databases for matching/similar column names but I wasn't able to find the table.

I have a list of values that would be associated with the `reason_id`. I'd like to search for tables that contain the list I have. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the query I was running to search for columns:

```sql
select 
  t.name as Table_Name,
  SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as schema_name,
  c.name as Column_Name
from
  sys.tables as t
  inner join 
  sys.columns c
  on
  t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
where 
  c.name like '%reason%'
```

Comment: Your table's definition does not contain a foreign key constraint that points back to the source table?

Comment: That's a good start. Next format the output grouped by table, as valid SQL for a search in all columns of the table matching the filter. Writing SQL to create valid SQL is a great way to improve your SQL understanding; call back with any specific difficulties you encounter.

Comment: I presume there's no table where t.name like '%reason%'...

Comment: @willOEM: I think that was implied by "the company that manages our DBs isn't the most competent".

Comment: No table like %reason% that contains the values I'm searching for. And the documentation on our DBs is limited at best, so mapping fk and pk is one my future tasks.

Comment: Have you tried scanning for views/procedures/functions that reference the key? `select object_name(object_id) from sys.sql_modules where definition like '%reason%'` (assuming this is T-SQL)

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS you are using, you should do a Google search for procedures that will search for particular values in any column and table of a database.  I have never used one of these myself, but I know some people who rely on them.

Comment: @MattW - I tried this and got no returns. Thanks though.

Comment: @willOEM - I've done a little bit of searching, looks like I'll be doing some more though. Thanks.

Comment: So, no foreign key means your column might be referencing values that don't exist any more. That would make finding the other end of the relationship much harder - if it even exists. Is it possible that the reason definitions are hardcoded in whatever application is accessing the database and simply don't exist in the database itself?

Comment: @MattW - Thanks for the food for thought, I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to find the related data in other tables.

I'd try with tools such as [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) or [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). Both are free and you won’t go wrong with any of these.

If you want to do it with SQL only then identify all columns in all tables that have the same data type. To do so use `sys.columns, sys.types and sys.tables` views. Once you find all columns just try start writing queries for each table until you find the right one.

I’d go with something like  this

```
select COUNT(*)
from tableX
where tableX.matchedColumn in
(
    -- take 100 or more random rows from the original table
    -- if result gives you a number that is near to the number of values listed here then you are most probably on the right track
)
```